# Xamarin.Forms - Constraints within RelativeLayout

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have created a basic page with an image, some labels and an input using Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio for a cross-platform app. The problem is that when the app is loaded on iOS and Android, it seems like my constraints did nothing and every element is disproportionate.

The code is simple, but I would like more clarification on why my constraints aren't enough to control the size/positions of the elements on the page throughout platforms.
Here is the expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

And here is the actual result:

[image: Actual Result]

Here is the code that *should* be constraining the size and position of these elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage Title="Smartie" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Smartie.Login" BackgroundImage="smartie_bg.png">
<ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <Image Source="smartie_logo.png" x:Name="smartieLogo" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.4}" Margin="50" />

            <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="20" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=250}" HeightRequest="300" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}">
                <Label Text="SETUP" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" Margin="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" />
                <Label Text="Access Code:" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=80}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" />
                <Entry Placeholder="Access Code" TextColor="Black" Margin="75" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=50}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" />
                <Button Text="CONFIRM" HorizontalOptions="Center" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=1,Constant=100}" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Factor=0, Property=Y, Constant=200}" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

What other constraints do I need? Or perhaps I'm not using the correct layout for this occasion? Maybe a stack layout would be better?

Comment: I use your code at my side, but I get the different screenshot, so I guess that there is problem for your image, can you share one demo here, I will use your image to test.

Comment: @CherryBu Thanks for your help, what do you mean by share on demo - do you mean share the image file or? Also, I have solved the issue by instead using a grid layout. I will share the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by instead using a grid, and using the row definition height to limit the size of the image. I know this is sort of dodging around the problem that `RelativeLayout` caused above, but the grid layout was actually a better solution here anyway. For further information as to why this was better, there is a great tech talk and document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance).

As for the code that solved my issue:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="0">
            <Image Source="smartie_logo.png" x:Name="smartieLogo"/>
        </Frame>

        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Margin="20">
            <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10" Spacing="25" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="1">
                <Label Text="SETUP" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left"/>
                <Label Text="Access Code:" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" x:Name="AccessCodeLabel"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="Access Code" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Button Text="CONFIRM" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="confirmButton" Clicked="AccessCodeConfirmed" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```